# Can't change value of a variable in JS, using parseFromString

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, variables, google-chrome-extension, domparser

I have this line at the very beginning of a Chrome extension:

```
var macroXML = parser.parseFromString(localStorage["myMacro"], "text/xml").getElementsByTagName("section");
```

After doing some changes, I try to update macroXML, but nothing happens.

```
alert(macroXML[1]);
macroXML[1] = 'RAWR';
alert(macroXML[1]);
```

No errors, no anything. It outputs the exact same thing.

Anyone perhaps know why?

Comment: It's an XMLDocument. Can it not be changed or something? :/

Comment: I suspect not.  Copy it to an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with a dynamic nodes list. It will change if the document changes, e.g. to remove the second element from the list you can do:

```
macroXML[1].parentNode.removeChild(macroXML[1]);
```

Or you replace it by a different node:

```
var newNode = macroXML[1].ownerDocument.createElement("section");
macroXML[1].parentNode.replaceChild(newNode, macroXML[1]);
```

But you cannot work with that list as you would do with an array - for that you need an actual array. You can copy the list like this:

```
var macroArray = Array.prototype.slice.apply(macroXML);
macroArray[1] = 'RAWR';
```

This will work as expected then.